# Add State Field In Prestashop Back Ofiice Order Table

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, prestashop

I am trying to add the state field in my bo Order Table in prestashop. In my AdminOrdersController.php file i have use this code to get the address field:

```
$this->_select = '
            addr.address1 AS `address`,

$this->_join = '
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'address` addr ON (a.`id_address_delivery` = addr.`id_address`)
```

and in my $this->fields_list array i have:

```
'address' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Address')
        ),
```

Thats work for the address..and i am trying to do something familiar but no great results. when i am trying to get the name of the state i get only the id_state.

i have use:

```
$this->_select = '
        go.id_state AS `city`,
$this->_join = '
        LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'address` go ON (a.`id_address_delivery` = go.`id_address`)
```

and in the array:

```
'city' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('City')
            ),
```

I know its a mysql syntax error. How i write it correctly? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have one missing `'` in your code before `$this->_join = '`

Keep in mind that this sql will only get you a `id_state` not a state name

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing the same thing, but I got it working in `PS 1.6.1.4`.
In the `AdminOrdersController.php` (overriding it is better):

```
$this->_select = 'css.name AS `state`,
```

Then a bit further on:

```
$this->_join = '
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'address` ca ON (a.`id_address_delivery` = ca.`id_address`)
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'state` css ON (ca.`id_state` = css.`id_state`)
```

Finally call it:

```
'state' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('State')
),
```

If this doesn't make sense, have a look at the `AdminOrdersController.php` file and make an override that includes this. You might also want to check out [this tutorial](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/281786-show-customer-group-on-orders-page-in-backoffice/).